# How do you update TableServiceClient in ASP.NET Core, to point to a secondary region, when using Azure geo redundant (RA-GRS) table storage?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-table-storage, automatic-failover

I am using the latest `Azure.Data.Tables` nuget package, version `12.3.0` to connect to Azure table storage in an ASP.NET Core C# Application.

My application needs to failover to a secondary region for **reads** if the primary region fails.

Currently the setup the of `TableServiceClient` is done in the Startup.cs as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{     
   services.AddSingleton(new TableServiceClient(new Uri("PrimaryRegionConnectionURL"), new DefaultAzureCredential()));
}
```

How do would I update the current instance of `TableServiceClient` with an instance pointed to the secondary region? Is there a better approach to achieve this failover?

Just to Clarify:
I am aware that the client doesn't support failing over and the team have created a ticket to look at this feature in future.
I realize I need to have a new instance of `TableServiceClient`.

I am just not sure **how I would replace the one created at startup with a new instance pointed to the secondary instance** at the time of failure.

Here is that code that consumes the `TableServiceClient`

```
    public class TableRepository : ITableStorageRepository
{
    readonly TableServiceClient _serviceClient;

    public TableRepository(TableServiceClient serviceClient)
    {
        _serviceClient = serviceClient;
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<T>> GetPartitionEntities<T>(string partitionKey, string tableName)
        where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        var listOfEntities = new List<T>();

        var tableClient = _serviceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);

        var queryResults = tableClient.QueryAsync<T>(filter => filter.PartitionKey == partitionKey);

        await foreach (var row in queryResults) 
        {
            listOfEntities.Add(row);
        }

        return listOfEntities;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the SDK you're using?

Comment: @GauravMantri I am using a nuget package `Azure.Data.Tables` that is part of the `azure-sdk-for-net`  found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to accomplish it, but this is how I would have done it considering I have to handle the logic of switching between primary and secondary endpoint myself.

First, I would have created two instances of `TableServiceClient` - one for the primary and other for secondary.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{  
    Dictionary<string, TableServiceClient> tableServiceClients = new Dictionary()
    {
      "Primary",  new TableServiceClient(new Uri("PrimaryRegionConnectionURL"), new DefaultAzureCredential()),
      "Secondary",  new TableServiceClient(new Uri("SecondaryRegionConnectionURL"), new DefaultAzureCredential())
    }
    services.AddSingleton(tableServiceClients);
}
```

Next, I would have extracted the logic for fetching the entities in a separate function and passed the client to that function (let's call that `GetPartitionEntitiesImpl`).

Then in `GetPartitionEntities` method I would have tried to get the entities from the primary endpoint and catch the exception. If the exception indicates primary endpoint failure, I would have called `GetPartitionEntitiesImpl` function again and try to fetch the entities from the secondary endpoint.

```
public class TableRepository : ITableStorageRepository
{
    readonly TableServiceClient _primaryServiceClient, _secondaryServiceClient;

    public TableRepository(Dictionary<string, TableServiceClient> tableServiceClients)
    {
        _primaryServiceClient = tableServiceClients["Primary"];
        _secondaryServiceClient = tableServiceClients["Secondary"];
    }

    public async Task<ICollection<T>> GetPartitionEntities<T>(string partitionKey, string tableName)
        where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        try
        {
            return await GetPartitionEntitiesImpl(_primaryServiceClient, partitionKey, tableName);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
          //Check if there is a need for failover
          if (shouldTrySecondaryEndpoint)
          {
              return await GetPartitionEntitiesImpl(_secondaryServiceClient, partitionKey, tableName);
          }
        }
    }

    private async Task<ICollection<T>> GetPartitionEntitiesImpl<T>(TableServiceClient serviceClient, string partitionKey, string tableName)
        where T : class, ITableEntity, new()
    {
        var listOfEntities = new List<T>();

        var tableClient = serviceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);

        var queryResults = tableClient.QueryAsync<T>(filter => filter.PartitionKey == partitionKey);

        await foreach (var row in queryResults) 
        {
            listOfEntities.Add(row);
        }

        return listOfEntities;
    }

}
```

Also, please take a look at the code of older Azure Storage SDK (version 9.x) regarding the logic for switching between primary and secondary endpoints. That SDK handles this scenario rather well.

Comment: thank you for your solution, I think this gives me a good start many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic failover using the same client is not currently supported; to use the secondary region, a separate `TableServiceClient` would be needed.  More context is available here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/25456

Work for adding support is being tracked here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/25710

Comment: Hi Jesse, I am aware that the client doesn't support this, and realize I need to have a new instance of `TableServiceClient`. I am just not sure how I would replace the one created at startup with a new instance pointed to the secondary instance at the time of failure. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hi Jesse I have updated the question to try and make it clearer, and thank you to the team for tracking my failover question.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include code where you are using TableServiceClient?

Comment: @GauravMantri that code is in the original post as is the nuget package and verion

Comment: You included the code where you're configuring the dependency. I was more interested in seeing the code where you're injecting this dependency. It is quite clear that you will need 2 different TableServiceClient instances at least as of now - one pointing to the primary endpoint and other to secondary endpoint.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you for clarifying, I will add the code

Comment: Added an answer. Not sure if this is the best approach but it should give you some idea about how to proceed. Please do share the solution you come up. I would be very much interested in knowing about that.